# Sending email with Sparkpost using Java

Tags: java, sparkpost

I am trying to send an email with Sparkpost using JAVA. I am getting an exception "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException" and the complete error log is below. Could any one please help me on this.

```
Oct 22, 2018 4:28:10 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.encPath(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Comment: Have you checked that the version of HTTP Client you are using is the same that is used by the SparkPost library? https://github.com/SparkPost/java-sparkpost/blob/master/pom.xml#L257

Comment: We are using Sparkpost-lib-0.19 library and commons-httpclient-3.1.

Comment: Can you update your question with the full stack trace? None of what you show there has the SparkPost library in the trace.